# Best way to interate in for loop to get field values in array

Tags: lua

I've got a array that I am flipping through to process some lines of text. This code works but I know there has to be a better way to do it.

```
 local text_matches = {
                  {"^range:","range"},
                  {"^saving throw:","save"},
                  {"^casting time:","castingtime"},
                  {"^components:","components"},
                  {"^area of effect:","aoe"},
                  {"^duration:","duration"},
                  {"^school:","school"},
                  {"^sphere:","sphere"},
                  {"^type:","type"},

                  {"^arcane ","school","(.*)$"},
                  {"^phantasmal ","school","(.*)$"},
                  {"^druidic ","sphere","(.*)$"},
                  {"^clerical ","sphere","(.*)$"},

                  };
```

and then I use the text_matches in a for loop

```
  for _, sFind in ipairs(text_matches) do
    local sMatch = sFind[1];
    local sValue = sFind[2];
    local sFilter = sFind[3];
    if (string.match(sLine:lower(),sMatch)) then
      bProcessed = true;
      setTextValue(nodeSpell,sLine,sMatch,sValue,sFilter);
    end
  end
```

I'd rather not have to assign values to sMatch/sValue/sFilter like I am. I'm still new to certain aspects of Lua but I suspect there has to be a way to  use a for loop AND get all 3 values for each entry in the array?

something like `for sMatch, sValue, sFilter (text_matches) do`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a way. ipairs is an iterator. No one stops you from writing your own.

Let's have a look at how ipairs works:

```
function iter (a, i)
  i = i + 1
  local v = a[i]
  if v then
    return i, v
  end
 end

 function ipairs (a)
   return iter, a, 0
 end
```

For more details refer to [Programming in Lua: 7.3 Stateless Iterators](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.3.html)

> When Lua calls `ipairs(a)` in a `for` loop, it gets three values: the
>   `iter` function as the iterator, `a` as the invariant state, and
>   `zero` as the initial value for the control variable. Then, Lua calls
>   `iter(a, 0)`, which results in `1, a[1]` (unless `a[1]` is already
>   `nil`). In the second iteration, it calls `iter(a, 1)`, which results
>   in `2, a[2]`, and so on, until the first `nil` element.

Now instead of `a[i]` we're going to return `a[i][1]`, `a[i][2]` and `a[i][3]`.

```
function myFancyThree(a)

    return function(a, i)
             i = i + 1
             local v = a[i]
             if v then
               return i, v[1], v[2], v[3]
             end
           end, a, 0
end
```

Then we can do something like

```
for i, a,b,c in myFancyThree(text_matches) do
  print(a,b,c)
end
```

I didn't put too much thought into it. I'm sure there are things you can do better but it should be enough to get you startet.

Just read anything about the generic for loop, iterators and stateless iterators you can find in Programming in Lua and the Lua reference manual.

I leave it up to you to find a better name than myFancyThree :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I didn't even consider writing a "new" for loop function. I'll play about with it ;)